# Swig: Calling struct pointers from Java

Tags: java, swig

I have the following line of code inside the c.h file:

```
typedef struct ppr_my_struct* ppr_my_type;
```

I should mention that ppr_my_type is not defined in any of the .h files

I created a swigTest.i file that references a bunch of .h files (including the file noted above). An example is shown below:

```
%module swigTest
%{
#include "C:\blah\a.h"
#include "C:\blah\b.h"
#include "C:\blah\c.h"
%}
#include "C:\blah\a.h"
#include "C:\blah\b.h"
#include "C:\blah\c.h"
```

I ran swig to auto-generate the java files. The result of the "typedef struct ppr_my_struct* ppr_my_type;" is shown below:

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct {
  private long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct(long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I get a valid instance of SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct to use in my java code? If I do:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct blah = new SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct();
```

it throws a fatal exception when the object is used later in the code (presumably because I did not initialize it by calling the other constructor with which passes in a Pointer).  No other methods in the remaining swig java files return an instance of SWIGTYPE_p_p_ppr_my_struct for me to use.  What do I have to do in order to get a valid instance?

Thanks!